# React navigation Get stack navigator header height inside class component (without hooks)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I know it is possible to get stack header height with the following hook (V5):

```
import { useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

Is there a workaround for a class component ? For the moment I am using a context consumer to get the height inside the render() function :

```
<HeaderHeightContext.Consumer>
                  {headerHeight => (   
    ...
    )}
</HeaderHeightContext.Consumer>
```

But I would like to have the headerHeight outside my render() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried in your component something like this:

```
static contextType = HeaderHeightContext;

componentDidMount() {
   console.log(this.context); // this is your height
}
```

From [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype):

> The contextType property on a class can be assigned a Context object created by React.createContext(). This lets you consume the nearest current value of that Context type using this.context

Comment: Im getting an: 
`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.context.headerHeight')`

Comment: Here's how I tested:
`class AddProductScreen extends React.Component {  

  static contextType = HeaderHeightContext;
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { headerHeight } = this.context;
    console.log(headerHeight);
   ...
}
`

Comment: No more error, but headerHeight value is `undefined`

Comment: 56 I guess that's what I'm looking for ? Could you just explain how did we get that ?

Comment: this is BS : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headerHeight')

Comment: you shared a documentation of React not RN